# Using Parse.Object type pointers with JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, pointers, parse-platform, nosql

I'm using **parse.com** with a *cordova* based mobile app and I ran into an issue dealing with a list page that has different type of items. For the sake of the example, imgine three types of items- **text, image and event**.

My solution for this problem was to create three different types of parse classes: `Image`, `Text` and `Event`, Each with it's own special fields, and a `Message` class that has a *pointer* *data* field from type `Parse.Object` that will contain anyone of the three type of classes.

The problem is I'm not compleley sure on how to make the *data* field point to an `Parse.Object`. There's no option for this in *Data Browser* and, as I understand, in the *JS SDK* this happens autoamtically the first time you set a value from some type for the field. (e.g If I save `Image` on *data*, it'll lock me to use only `Image` from here on out).

Would love to hear if anyone know how to achive this or, if enyone has different idea for making a list with differetn types of items.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like `Single table inheritance` pattern [here more info](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html). My suggestion is to keep all three classes in one Parse table called `Message` and in `Message`  table should have field `type` which will have value for concrete type of your objects. In that way you will query, filter and sort only one table. You can also easily add more objects to this table.

Keeping all objects in one table have pros and cons. Please consider well your decision.

Comment: This is exactly my aproach above (used `data` instead of `type`). If you meant to have type as JSON data, that's not possible for me because one of the types have a pointer to another class as well.

Comment: for the column `type` i mean simple `String` column which will contain on of the following values: image, text or event.

Comment: and what about all the different fields? e.g `Image` has `url` field, `Text` has `content` field and `Event` has `startDate` & `endDate` fields.

Comment: `single table inheritence` pattern says to put all fields in one table - `Messages` it will looks a little bit strange but I think is a good solution.

Comment: That wouldn't cut it I'm afraid, since I have some classes with a lot of fields. Also, in case i'm adding more types, I'll have to change the signature of the class accross everything that is already saved.

Thanks,
I'm looking for better solution though.

Comment: yes, in that case my suggestion is not good, because you have existing data. other thing that i can suggest is to create Collection Message, with columns Image, Text and Event that will be pointers to existing objects..